What is the optimal way to place a BNC connection point on a printed circuit board?
I am working on my first RF project and I have two signals coming onto my board through a BNC connection. I have selected this BNC but their data sheet is not very informative.
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/amphenol-rf/112536/1011730
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/catsy.582/112536.pdf
I need to terminate them into a 50 ohm load. Do I need to route the center pin of the BNC connection into the terminal of a 50 ohm resistor and connect all of the outer mounting pins (which I assume are the BNC input signals ground) to the PCB power supply ground and the other terminal of the resistor or will I have problems connecting multiple signal grounds to the PCB ground? Thanks!

Can you elaborate on what the actual load on the board is? Is it an LNA? A mixer? An ADC? Is it already terminated to 50-ohm?

Over what bandwidth, to what maximum VSWR? What other connections are made to the board? Do you have any EMC concerns (emissions, susceptibility, transients..)?

The four outer pins are connected the coax outer conductor and also serve as mechanical mounting, and all four should connect to PCB RF ground plane (which might be same as power ground). The signal center pin should connect to trace on your PCB that is sized to act as 50 ohm transmission line and routes to the receiver device on the board. If the receiver device has a high-impedance input, then you would place 50 Ohm resistor as termination to RF ground at where the trace enters the receiving device input pin, rather than at the BNC connector input. But termination required depends on details of the receiver device, which is the load of the transmission line, so read that device's datasheet carefully. Make sure the RF ground plane is continuous under the connector, signal trace, and to the ground pins of the receiver device.  Depending on the other characteristics of the signal source, you may consider if the board circuitry needs to be AC coupled or if just the termination resistor needs to be AC coupled, which is done by placing small capacitor in series.
